# DNS: Delegate resolution of a subdomain to another name server

Tags: bind, ubuntu-14.04

I am setting up a DNS server at home to make it easier for me to alias some of my local servers, and also as a project to better understand DNS. Since I am new to this please forgive (and correct if you would) any mistakes with terminology!

The purpose of my local DNS server is to use my domain for accessing some of my local machines. So, let's say my domain is `my-domain.com`. I have a media server at home that I want to access as `media.my-domain.com`, and I have two local DNS servers that I use for this purpose. These DNS servers delegate to Google DNS for other queries.

Here is my zone file for `my-domain.com`, which is stored in `/etc/bind/zones/db.my-domain.com` on my local DNS server `ns1`:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.my-domain.com. admin.my-domain.com. (
                  3     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
@   IN  NS  ns1.my-domain.com.
@   IN  NS  ns2.my-domain.com.
;
; name servers - A records
ns1.my-domain.com.  IN  A   10.55.55.55
ns2.my-domain.com.  IN  A   10.55.55.56
;
; 10.55.55.0/24 - A records
media.my-domain.com.    IN  A   10.55.55.100
```

Here is my options file which is stored in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` on my local DNS server `ns1`:

```
acl "trusted" {
    10.55.55.0/24; # home network
};
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    listen-on { 10.55.55.55; };
    allow-transfer {none; }; # disable zone transfers

    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8; # google1
        8.8.4.4; # google2
    };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Here `10.55.55.0/24` is my local subnet, and `ns1` and `ns2` are my primary and secondary DNS servers, respectively.

I am using `my-domain.com` for other purposes on the internet, so for example when I access `admin.my-domain.com` it takes me to the admin console of a publicly visible website. Meaning, if you perform an `nslookup` on `admin.my-domain.com` from Google's DNS servers you will see it mapped to a globally-accessible public IP address.

Unfortunately, after I implemented my local DNS servers I cannot resolve `admin.my-domain.com` correctly. My `nslookup` requests hit my local DNS servers, which are not configured for this subdomain, and I get "No answer" from my local DNS.

The behavior I would like, instead, is for my DNS servers to forward requests for `my-domain.com` to Google DNS, and to only provide answers for `ns1.my-domain.com`, `ns2.my-domain.com`, and `media.my-domain.com`. I have seen some questions that are similar to mine, but the responses tend to be to create a single zone file for each subdomain. Is this really the only way? I would really like to be able to say, "if I've specified a rule for `x.my-domain.com` then follow that rule. Otherwise, delegate up the chain (to Google DNS in my case)."

I am not sure of how to troubleshoot this with Google since I'm not really clear on the terminology, and since I am a total noob I don't know where to begin on fixing it myself. Is what I'm asking for even possible? Any help on how I might implement this behavior, or search for it, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you configured Bind to be authoritative for the whole of `example.com`.

So you must either configure your local Bind to hold not only your internal DNS records, but also a copy of all your public DNS records in the zone file for `example.com`.

Alternatively rather than making Bind authoritative for `example.com` you reserve a subdomain of example.com for your internal use, make your internal DNS only authoritative for that.  i.e. create a zone called `home.example.com` and use `media.home.example.com`. That way you can't have conflicting records in your internal and public DNS.